# Slick Slider loaded with display:none creates bad initiation

Tags: jquery

I've got a gallery of thumbs and a Slick slider in a layer on top (z-index), hidden through css with display:none.
When clicking on of the thumbs the display setting changes to block and the slider shows, But:
The width/height/left/right etc of the slides are never calculated, check out this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/5eceg5yd/1/

html:

```
<a href="#">show slider</a>
<div id="addressesList">
    <div class="addressBox">
        <p>Mrs Name
            <br>Address1
            <br>London SE15 4DH
            <br>United Kingdom
            <br>
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="addressBox">
        <p>Mrs Name
            <br>Address 2
            <br>New York SE15 4DH
            <br>United States of America
            <br>
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="addressBox">
        <p>Mrs Name
            <br>Address3
            <br>London SE15 4DH
            <br>United Kingdom
            <br>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
#addressesList {
    display: none    
}
```

jQuery:

```
var slider = $('#addressesList').slick({   
});

$('a').on("click", function() {
    $('#addressesList').css('display', 'block'); 
});
```

Its as if the slider is loaded with display: none, nothing get calculated. Maybe its completly obvious that this should happen but I cant figure out how to create a "lightbox" kind of slider without this working.

Comment: in Javascript/jQuery it is generally not possible to calculate the dimensions of an item which is set to `display:none;` ... one way you may be able to overcome this is to run this command after the `display:block;` - `$('#addressesList').get(0).slick.setPosition();`

Answer (score 67, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/5eceg5yd/8/

I updated your fiddle with the code to fix this:

```
$('#addressesList').get(0).slick.setPosition();
```

**update:**

```
$('.your-element').slick('setPosition');
```

is better for newer releases, as mentioned here: https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick#methods

Comment: works like a charm!  $('.offers-accordion-element').slideToggle(1000);
    $('.offers-carousel').get(0).slick.setPosition();

Comment: nice! took me an afternoon to get the working properly!

Comment: Thank you!! Five years later and this is still an issue. In my case, the slick container is hidden on page load, then only visible using a jquery.modal call.  This fix works perfectly without messing with height and overflow.

Answer (score 14):

Use the following on the outer container instead of display:none

height: 0px;
overflow-y: hidden;

Works as intended :)